# How to invert an interpolating function?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have an ODE where $\theta$ is a function of r. I solved the ODE using NDSolve so I got a solution as an interpolating solution. Now, I want to plot the polar plot for which I need r as a function of $\theta$. Is there a way in which I can invert the function $\theta (r)$ or somehow obtain $r(\theta)$?

Comment: You will generally get better answers if you provide a concrete example for everyone to work with. Provide function definitions and other code in `InputForm` so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, I want to plot the polar plot for which I need r as a function of

Just a small something to get you started

```
eqns = {θ''[r] + θ[r] == Sin[θ[r]], θ[0] ==
     1, θ'[0] == Pi/2};
ndsolve = NDSolveValue[eqns, θ, {r, 0, 5}];
functionplot = Plot[ndsolve[r], {r, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio];
inverseplot = 
  ParametricPlot[{ndsolve[r], r}, {r, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio];
GraphicsRow[{functionplot, inverseplot}]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I want to make a polar plot.